# What's the history of the use of crude oil for transportation before the Industrial Revolution?

Tags: thermodynamics, technology, energy, ancient, inventions

What's the history of the use of crude oil for transportation before the Industrial Revolution?

Wiktionary says the Latin word [*petroleum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/petroleum#Latin), from *petra* (“rock”) + *oleum* (“oil”), is medieval Latin, so presumably at least the medievals had uses for it.

Comment: The question seems a bit broad. Could you narrow it down to a particular aspect mentioned in the "History" section of the relevant Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petroleum)?

Comment: @njuffa I've narrowed the scope down to the use of oil for energy in transportation.

Comment: I seem to recall that petroleum was a cheaper replacement for whale oil, and thus its early uses were the previous uses of whale oil.  (illumination, lubrication, soap, ...) So, probably not for transportation.

Comment: For transportation you would need a an engine to burn it. That took quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

Indirect uses for transportation: "Petroleum is not a recent discovery, it was known to various ancient peoples in Asia, North Africa, Europe, and America where it seeped to the surface and was used in various forms for at least 70,000 years. It was most widely used to **caulk ships, pave roads**..." ([History of Oil: Regions and Uses of Petroleum in the Classical and Medieval Periods](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-3-319-02330-4_38-1#:%7E:text=During%20the%20Classical%20Period%2C%20the,the%20bitumen%20deposits%20of%20the))

Comment: I had more in mind petroleum being used to move/power transportation devices than to build them.